# How do I flash a button with a keypress in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter button widget that I'd like to flash when a key is pressed. The key is bound to the root window. I have tried binding the key to the button as well as the root window, setting the button state to ACTIVE and setting the button takefocus=1, but the button doesn't flash when the key is pressed. The button is really for show, because it's not being clicked on, but I'd like it to flash anyway.

```
root = Tk()
leftButton = Button(root, text="F", borderwidth=0)
root.bind("<KeyPress-F>", buttonPress1)
root.bind("<KeyPress-f>", buttonPress1)
leftButton.grid(row=3, column = 0)
leftButton.bind("<KeyPress-F>")
leftButton.bind("<KeyPress-f>")
leftButton.configure(state=ACTIVE)
leftButton.configure(takefocus=1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the button flash, but (if you do?) put the process for this inside a function named buttonpress1 and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

(Got it) I would do this by making a button change colour on a keypress in a function like so:

```
import tkinter as tk

r = tk.Tk()

l = tk.Label(text = 'press f to make button flash')
l.pack()

b = tk.Button(text = 'useless button')
b.config(bg = 'lightgrey')
b.pack()

def flash(event):
    b.config(bg = 'yellow')
    r.after(100, lambda: b.config(bg = 'lightgrey'))

r.bind("<KeyPress-f>", flash)

r.mainloop()
```

This makes the button change to yellow in colour for 1 tenth of a second which is as like a flash as I could get :)

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#  TkButtonFLASH.py                         # execfile( "TkButtonFLASH.py" )
#  
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

class TestButtonFLASH():

    def FlashStep1(                         self, anEvent ):
        KeyHANDLER( anEvent )                                 # .DEBUG
        if self.LOCK_STEP1:                                   # .IF  .LOCK_STEP1
            return                                            #      .RET
            '''
            print "LOCK_STEP1: blocks further .bind() events ",
                  "from entering into an unfinished transaction ",
                  "state,\n            still in waiting <state> ",
                  "before .after() finishes the started ",
                  "transaction & UNLOCKs LOCK_STEP1"
            return                                            #      .RET after print
            '''
        self.LOCK_STEP1         = True                        # .SET .LOCK_STEP1
        self.PUSH_POP           = self.leftButton['bg']       # .PUSH current value in Class.attribute
        self.leftButton['bg']   = 'yellow'                    # .SET
        self.leftButton.after( 100, self.FlashStep2 )         # .SCHEDULE 100 [ms] self.FlashStep2()
        self.leftButton.update()                              # .UPD GUI

    def FlashStep2(                         self ):
        self.leftButton['bg']   = self.PUSH_POP               # .POP/.SET previous value from .attribute
        self.LOCK_STEP1         = False                       # .SET !LOCK_STEP1
        self.leftButton.update()                              # .UPD GUI

    def ExitPROCESS(                        self ):           # MVC-Controller-Part ..
        if tkMessageBox.askokcancel( "Quit GUI", "Do you really wish to quit?" ):
            self.master.destroy()
        pass

    def __init__(                           self, master ):   # MVC-setup { Model + Visual + Controller }
        # -------------------------------------------------------------- UI-state-var(s), not used so-far/anymore :)
        self.PUSH_POP            = ""
        self.LOCK_STEP1          = False                                # .SET !LOCK_STEP1
        # -------------------------------------------------------------- UI-construction ----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.master              = master
        self.master.title(      "Test TkButtonFLASH v0.0" )             # .title()
        self.master.geometry(   "400x400-50-50" )                       # .geometry
        #elf.master.iconbitmap()                                        # .iconbitmap
        self.master.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.ExitPROCESS )    # [X]-overide ---------------------------
        self.master.lift()                                              # raise window

        self.leftButton          = tk.Button( self.master, text = "F", borderwidth = 1, bg = "green" )
        self.leftButton.grid( row = 0, column = 0 )

        self.master.bind( "<KeyPress-F>", self.FlashStep1 )
        self.master.bind( "<KeyPress-f>", self.FlashStep1 )
        self.master.bind( "<KeyPress>",   KeyHANDLER )
        self.master.mainloop()

def KeyHANDLER( anEvent ):                                              # .DEBUG utility
    print "<Key>-event: ", anEvent.serial, anEvent.time, anEvent.char, anEvent.keysym, anEvent.keysym_num, str( anEvent.widget )

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app  = TestButtonFLASH( root )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This Class-based approach uses the a two-step transaction and Class-attribute to store and carry the original **`['bg']`** value, to be restored back, after the 150 [ms] Flash.

### Need to add a protection of the two-step split transaction

as one may see from holding a Keyboard-key pressed for some time ( till BIOS typematic-rate setting timeouts and an auto-repeat function starts to fire .......................  events like a PKT -- pulemyot-Kalashnikova-tankovyj:

```
<Key>-event:  1240 323533265 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1241 323533296 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1242 323533343 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1243 323533375 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1244 323533390 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1245 323533437 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1246 323533468 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1247 323533500 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1248 323533515 s s 115 .
<Key>-event:  1249 323533562 s s 115 .
```

As seen from a raw `KeyHANDLER()` output, the rate of events slightly varies about 15-50 [msec], which is by far faster, than the two-step-Flash-transaction minimum time, so there would appear more transaction-"starts" before the first transaction finished.

Thus a primitive transaction locking was added to avoid such side-effect.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me, nor does the code form W1ll1amvl. Nothing happens to the button color. Changing the color of the button momentarily to emulate a flash is a great idea, but I can't seem to change the color in general, even when initially configuring a button.

Comment: @Steve any diagnostics on that observation? Adding a call to a self-reporting function alike `def KeyHANDLER( anEvent ):                 print "<Key>-event: ", anEvent.serial, anEvent.time, anEvent.char, anEvent.keysym, anEvent.keysym_num, str( anEvent.widget )` may help you drill down to the roots of the issue. **Also:** did you test inside just a terminal, or via IDLE IDE ? **And:** have you launched  `root.mainloop()` before trying the `.bind()`-configured handlers? **`<KeyPress-f>`** events do not appear in terminal before entering `root.mainloop()` while Mouse events, alike `<Enter>` do..

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of those diagnostics. I'm running it inside terminal, and the `.bind()` lines appear in the code before `root.mainloop()` (if those lines appear after `root.mainloop()` they don't work)

Comment: @Steve Good, Terminal-mode is for Tkinter prototyping "cleaner" than a Tk-based IDLE ( concurrent Tk-internalities may collide ). Will modify the code, to put the KeyHANDLER() self-reporting in place.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand what you meant about the KeyHandler function. When you run that program and press F does the button flash? It does not for me, and this is the kind of console output I get:  <br> 
`<Key>-event:  907 1677850096 F F 70 .'
<Key>-event:  915 1677850384 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  923 1677850631 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  931 1677851136 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  939 1677851637 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  943 1677851721 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  947 1677851806 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  951 1677851890 F F 70 .
<Key>-event:  955 1677851974 F F 70 .`